# Firefox - can I make firefox's default behaviour for pdf's be 'Download pdf to downloads folder, then open in acrobat'?

Tags: firefox, pdf, download, adobe-acrobat

I think title says it all. The options in the firefox options are to either open in browser, download, or have it open with a program (after downloading to temp). Is there a way that I can make it download and then open the file with acrobat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an addon for something like that.

I quickly whipped up a script which might do the job.

I tested it on my PC and it works flawless.

After downloading a PDF file to the User Downloads folder it runs the PDF instantly.

You can  [Download it from here](http://www.tewoshien.com/downloads/monitor_pdf.zip)

This is the code :

```
Set ob = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    UsrPrfl = ob.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Userprofile%")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fo = fs.GetFolder( UsrPrfl & "\Downloads")
Set xt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
xt.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
xt.Add "pdf", True
Do
WScript.Sleep 50
For Each fl In fo.Files
  If xt.Exists(fs.GetExtensionName(fl.Name)) And fl.DateLastModified = Now Or fl.DateCreated = Now Then
    ob.Run fl
  End If
Next
Loop
```

Once you click it, it will loop infinitly.

If you want it to start with windows, then place it in the startup folder.

If you want to stop it manually,

you have to open Task Manager and kill the wscript.exe process at the command line.

Or if you enabled Command Line in View -> Select Columns in Task Manager,

you can kill the process by name.

This script monitors the folder Downloads in your User profile folder,

and runs the pdf after it has been downloaded.

Good luck

**This works only on Windows**

Comment: This seems to work. The only issue I seem to have is that sometimes it seems to try to open partially downloaded PDFs. This has only occurred a few times, and I haven't studied it in detail, so it could be that it is a issue on my part, and not with the code.